# Error when inheriting in python

Tags: python

I'm using a not-well-known framework called IPKISS; hopefully, this does not matter.

```
from ipkiss.all import *    

class ElectrodePair(Structure):
    """An electrode component to be used for a PPLN design."""

    __name_prefix__ = "ELECTRODE_PAIR"

    width = PositiveNumberProperty(required = True)
    height = PositiveNumberProperty(required = True)
    seperation = PositiveNumberProperty(required = True)

    lay1 = Layer(number = 1, name = "boundaries")

    def define_elements(self, elems):
        left = ShapeRectangle(center = (-self.seperation*0.5,0.), box_size = (self.width, self.height))
        right = ShapeRectangle(center = (self.seperation*0.5,0.), box_size = (self.width, self.height)) 

        elems += Boundary(layer = self.lay1, shape = left)
        elems += Boundary(layer = self.lay1, shape = right)
        return elems



class ElectrodeStructure(ElectrodePair):
    """An array of electrodes."""

    __name_prefix__ = "ELECTRODE_STRUCTURE"

    amount = PositiveNumberProperty(required = True)
    spacing = PositiveNumberProperty(required = True)

    def define_elements(self, elems):
        electrodePair = ElectrodePair.__init__(self)
        elems += ARefX(reference = electrodePair, origin = (0,0), period_1d = self.spacing, n_o_periods_1d = self.amount)
        return elems



def main():
    FILE_NAME = "ElectrodeArray.gds"
    electrodeArray = ElectrodeStructure(amount = 10, height = 100., seperation = 20, spacing = 10., width = 2.)

    electrodeArray.write_gdsii(FILE_NAME)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have no idea why this is erroring.  The error is:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPKISS-2.4_ce-py2.7.egg/ipcore/properties/initializer.py",
line 327, in __init__ raise IpcoreAttributeException("Required property '%s' is not found in keyword arguments of '%s' initialization." % (p, str(type(self))))
ipcore.exceptions.exc.IpcoreAttributeException: Required property 'amount' is not found in keyword arguments of '<class '__main__.ElectrodeStructure'>' initialization.
```

It seems as though it's not happy with how I've passed my arguments, I've tried heaps of stuff and cannot get it to work.  Advice would be much appreciated.

I suspect the error is due to `electrodePair = ElectrodePair.__init__(self)`.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, you must specify an amount in your ElectrodePair initializer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ElectrodeStructure(ElectrodePair):
    [...]

    def define_elements(self, elems):
        electrodePair = ElectrodePair.__init__(self)
        [...]
```

When you create a new `ElectrodeStructure` in `main()`, you're passing keword arguments. Becuase you're not defining an `__init__` function in `ElectrodeStructure`, the super's `__init__` is being called with those arguments (including `amount`, so there's no error).

Then in `define_elements`, you're calling `__init__` again, except you aren't passing in any arguments, which is causing the error.

Additionally, this statement:

```
        electrodePair = ElectrodePair.__init__(self)
```

Is assigning the *return* value (likely `None`) of `ElectrodePair.__init__(self)` to `electrodePair`. I suspect you want something more like the following:

```
        electrodePair = ElectrodePair(amount=1, etc.)
```

It looks like you want composition, not inheritance; you could initialize your subclass in a proper `__init__` function (as @volcano describes), or just create an `ElectrodePair` class member, and not inherit at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add __init__ method to your *ElectrodeStructure* class, that - as @hd1 has pointed out - has to set *amount*:

```
class ElectrodeStructure(ElectrodePair):
    def __init__(self, amount):
        ElectrodePair.__init__(self)
```

The way you call ElectrodePair.__init__ is wrong, since in the absence of ElectrodeStructure.__init__ in your class the former will be called automatically

EDIT:

Couple of things I've noticed  on re-reading - you inherit from a class, and then within a class method you create an object of the parent class. Something is wrong here